# Spring Autowiring on service got always problems

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, autowired, jparepository

We have a really strange issue in our application and exhausted all options for troubleshooting, including checking for similar issues here on Stackoverflow. I simplyfied the code.

I have an Entity:

```
package com.packagename1.model;

@Entity
@Table(name = "LIBRI")
public class Libro implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8169686105733910187L;

@Id
@Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private Long id = 0l;

public Libro() { }

public Libro(Long id) { 
    this.id = id;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

I have a JPA Repository with some methods:

```
package packagename2.repo;

@Repository
public interface LibroRepository extends JpaRepository<Paziente, Long>{
    Boolean existsById(long libroId);

    Optional<Libro> findById(long libroId);
}
```

I got a service for interacting with that repository. That service has his own interface:

```
package packagename2.repo;

@Repository
public interface LibroRepository extends JpaRepository<Paziente, Long>{
    Boolean existsById(long libroId);
    
    Optional<Libro> findById(long libroId);
}
```

The service implementation.

```
    package com.packagename2.service;

@Service
public class LibroDaoServiceImpl implements LibroDaoService {
    @Autowired
    public LibroRepository repository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Boolean existsById(long libroId) {
        Boolean flag = null;
        flag = this.repository.existsById(libroId);
        if (null == flag)
            flag = false;
        return flag;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Libro findById(long libroId) throws NoSuchElementException {
        Libro libro = this.repository.findById(libroId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException("Libro not found for id: " + String.valueOf(libroId)));
        return Libro;
    }
}
```

And the class where I'm using the service.

```
package com.packagename3.component;

@StandardDatabase
public class LibroComponentImpl implements LibroComponent {
    @Autowired
    public LibroDaoServiceImpl service;
    
    ...
    
    private boolean verifyIfBookExits(long libroId) {
        try {
            Boolean book_existing = this.service.existsById(libroId);
            if (null == book_existing || !book_existing)
                messaggioErrore = "Wrong ID";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // logging
        }
    }
}
```

So this is the behaviour:

- on startup no errors;
- always got a null pointer exception on the line that invoke the service;

So some of my attempts:

- checked and all the packages are scanned on my Application.java;
- in another class, a Component I invoke the same service and no problem at all;
- in one of my many test I tried also to put the annotation @Componet on LibroComponentImpl;
- I had checked the I pass a non null value in the ID of libro;

I got no possible reason that can explain why Spring doesn't returns any error on autowiring yet it fails to set the field.

The line that gives the error is this one:

```
Boolean book_existing = this.service.existsById(libroId);
```

The stacktrace:
2022-08-05 14:30:22.416 ERROR 34208 --- [0.0-9000-exec-2] c.s.w.d.e.v.b.m.MisuraComponentImpl      : nu:::asa:::nc:::nm

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.packagename3.component.LibroComponentImpl.verifyIfBookExits(LibroComponentImpl.java:69) ~[classes/:na]
at com.packagename3.component.LibroComponentImpl.checkDataBooks(LibroComponentImpl.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
at com.packagename3.component.LibroComponentImpl.insertBook(LibroComponentImpl.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
at com.packagename4.component.JDBCDatabaseBackendLibro.insertMisura(JDBCDatabaseBackendCarewatch.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
at com.packagename5.component.component.LibroBackendWrapper.insertMisura(CarewatchBackendWrapper.java:150) ~[classes/:na]
at com.packagename6.component.service.LibroServiceImpl.insertMisura(MisuraServiceImpl.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) ~[cxf-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[cxf-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307) ~[cxf-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) ~[cxf-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:265) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:304) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:279) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at com.sidera.bonvicini.dataservice.security.filters.AuthJwtTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthJwtTokenFilter.java:80) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

Comment: What is @StandardDatabase? And how do you call the private method verifyIfBookExits?

Comment: There's nothing immediately obvious. Have you confirmed that it actually is `service` that is null? I see that you've declared a lot of these methods and variables as `Boolean` instead of `boolean` - maybe the NPE is being caused by an auto-unboxing in the non-simplified? Looks to me like you should be using `boolean` for the `exists*` methods, as they can only realistically give a yes/no answer.

Comment: @Jelaby yes, in one test I explicit put something like that " if (null != this.service) " and the code never enter the if.
I convert object Boolean to his primitive boolean and the problem remains.

Comment: How is `LibroComponentImpl` instantiated? Does it inherit `@Component` or is it created in a `@Bean` method, or is one created with `new` somewhere else?

Comment: It might be useful to post the NPE stack trace (you can obfuscate your class/package names but don't remove any lines)

Comment: NPE track posted in the opening post.

Comment: autowire the interface and not the implementation of the service

Comment: @AngeloImmediata I had already tried to use: Interface of the service, Implementation of the Service and directly the Repository. Nothing changed.

Comment: What is the annotation `StandardDatabase`? It doesn't seem a spring annotation; this means that the bean and all its properties are not managed by spring

Comment: @AngeloImmediata i tried also tu use only stantard Spring annotations Service and Component but it doesn't works anyway. Annotation StandardDatabase is inherited from the project, in theory it doesn't affect the Spring Container.

Comment: I fixed this, the only way to do it it's to get the application context and get manually from it the implementation of the service.

Comment: If you don't use spring annotations it's normal that the Instance will always be null; I guess StandardDatabase is a custom annotation you inherited and it's not a Spring one